# Retrieving Database Information and Showing in ListView with Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am working on an Android app that will allow the user to see restaurants in the city I live in. I am storing each restaurants information (name, address, telephone, hours, category, website) in an SQLite database.

What I am trying to do is to create a SortByAlpha activity that will list the restaurants by name in alphetically-descending order.

I understand that I should be using a Cursor to do this but I can't find a half decent tutorial, all of the "tutorials" I find are a bunch of code with minimal explanation. How can I do this / Where can I find a good tutorial?

Comment: If you're question has been answered, please select one of the answers below and mark as answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html), which bridges between Cursor and Adapter. Here is an example how to use it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html

Answer (score 0):

I would advise creating a "Restaurant" class that contains all the fields you will be listing. Then make your SQL call and specify "ORDER BY Name". Then create an ArrayList that can be fed to your custom list adapter! Also, if they were to somehow get out of order, just implement the "Comparable" interface for the Restaurant class and compare based on "Name" and then you can call Collections.sort(restaurantlist); to sort them in alphabetical order. I personally think ORDER BY is the easier way to go!